# CSS в одну строчку вместо в столбик

Tags: css

ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ЧТО ПОЧИТАТЬ ЛУЧШЕ ПРО ТО 
ЗАЧЕМ РЯДОМ С CSS ЕЩЁ .MIN.CSS
там всё в одну строчку

впервые с этим столкнулся
переносить можно? и вообще "природа" какая? зачем он появился

Comment: ну это если проект большой ...где css в несколько тысяч строк...типа магазин или крупный портал типа фейсбук или твиттер, майл.ru то css сжимают ...то появляется min.css

Comment: а если лендинг в 6-10 экранв тоже можно но особого смысла нет

Comment: `.min` означает минифицированный (сжатый) файл. Это делается в целях оптимизиации загрузки стилей и скриптов, файл весит меньше, а значит и загрузится быстрее. Сжатие происходит за счёт удаления пробелов и переносов строк, дабы получить всё в одну строчку с меньшим весом. На небольших страницах это не даст прироста, а вот на крупных проектах весьма сэкономит время загрузки страницы.